# Bach's WTC Edition; Fugues with Separated Voices

Tags: sheet-music, j-s-bach, fugue, polyphony

I know that there is an edition of Bach's WTC, in which every voice in the fugues is written in a seperate voice. This edition makes it easier to understand and practice the polyphony in the fugues. Unfortunately I couldn't find this anywhere (either for sale or download). Can you help me?

Comment: If you google for fugues wtc and looking for images or videos you’ll find many scores with staffs for each voice e.g. this here https://www.welltemperedclavier.org/de/node/34 also  in youtube: channel *open Goldberg* https://youtu.be/88HeQ8ychg8

Comment: In case you're curious, I recently made a recording of the C-Major Fugue from Book 1 in which I played each of the four voices on separate tracks and then panned them to different locations in the stereo space so that you can hear them separately. I thought it turned out pretty well! https://soundcloud.com/alexbasson/fugue-in-c-major

Answer (score 3):

This is an open score edition:

[https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=22539421382&searchurl=n%3D100121503%26sortby%3D17%26tn%3Dwell%2Btempered%2Bclavier%2Bjohann%2Bsebastian%2Bbach&cm_sp=snippet-*-srp1-*-title15](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=22539421382&searchurl=n%3D100121503%26sortby%3D17%26tn%3Dwell%2Btempered%2Bclavier%2Bjohann%2Bsebastian%2Bbach&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-title15)

[https://www.amazon.com/Bach-Well-Tempered-Clavier-Book-Score/dp/1105588645](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1105588645)

Comment: How can we see that this is a score edition with a staff for each voice? Oh, I sea: *open score* means right this! (But the example on the cover shows only the manuscript...)